# VBA regular expression REGEX : N.NN% or N.NNNN

Tags: regex, vba

Trying to create a regex expression that will allow either:
N.NN% or N.NNNN
Where N is a number between 0 and 9.

Here is the begining of the code:

```
^-?\d+\.\d{1,2}$
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can match either 2 digits which are followed by `%` or 2 other digits.

```
^-?\d+\.\d\d(?:%|\d\d)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2a0rAA/1)

If the first part should be 1-2 digits:

```
^-?\d+\.(?:\d{1,2}%|\d{4})$
```

Comment: Not sure if the OP intends one single digit to the left of the decimal or one-or-more? If only one, omit the `+` ...